# Simple Way to Get Data from WSS 3.0 List to Excel via Web Services

Tags: web-services, wss-3.0, excel

Is there any simple way to get live data from a WSS 3.0 list into Excel via web services or am I going to need to write code?

I understand I can export the list data, that is far too manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a add-in provided by Microsoft named as [Excel 2007 Add-in: Synchronizing Tables with SharePoint Lists](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345#overview) which lets you synchronize Excel 2007 tables with WSS SharePoint's List. Once you download and install this add-in then you can either read [MSDN documentation for synchronization of excel table step by step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636%28office.11%29.aspx) with list or [watch this tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwM3WpIMT6E).

Also if anyone don't want live data then they can develop a webpart which will get items from list and create a excel file for it. Let me know if you need tutorial for it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems like it is going in the correct direction, but this is a pre-existing, business-critical list so I am reluctant to use this tool. I suppose I will just have to write a tool myself that does this. It just really surprises me that there is not something that provides read only access to a custom list for WSS. Thanks for your suggestion. I will likely use that to solve other problems.